# ubuntu installer hangs forever at "executing late commands" on autoinstall

Tags: server, system-installation, cloud-init, curtin

I'm trying to install my Ubuntu server 20.04.03 using autoinstall. I don't have any "late-commands", but the installer hangs at "executing late commands".

Installer:

[image: installer screenshot]

full log:

[image: full log screenshot]

Full syslog: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wzrRTF3ptt/

"autoinstall" config I used:

```yaml
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  packages:
    - libpam-ssh-agent-auth
  # late-commands:
  #   - curtin in-target --target=/target -- sed -i.old '1s;^;auth [success=2 default=ignore] pam_ssh_agent_auth.so file=~/.ssh/authorized_keys  allow_user_owned_authorized_keys_file\n;' /etc/pam.d/sudo
  #   - curtin in-target --target=/target -- echo 'Defaults env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"' | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/SSH
  apt:
    geoip: true
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
    - arches: [amd64, i386]
      uri: http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu
    - arches: [default]
      uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
  interactive-sections:
    - identity
  keyboard: {layout: us, toggle: null, variant: ''}
  locale: en_US
  network:
    ethernets:
      ens160: {dhcp4: true}
    version: 2
  ssh:
    allow-pw: false
    authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa 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 cardno:F1D085922495
    install-server: true
  storage:
    layout:
      name: direct
  version: 1
```

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but I've found that it takes a really long time to apply security updates for 20.04. The security updates are mandatory, so you can not configure the installer to skip them.

Comment: @PJSingh I've waited for 12+ hours, and it is still stuck there.

Comment: Wow. I had to wait about 1/2 hr while security updates were downloading, so I think 12 hrs more than long enough. I have also noticed that the installer seems to magically get configurations (like late-commands) from somewhere, but I also have not been able to figure out *from where* ?! Unfortunately, I don’t have expertise in this area to help you. Hopefully someone with experience in cloud-init can step in and help.

Comment: You can disable auto update function by disabling network devices in Ubuntu installer.